# Format double with variable decimal precision

Tags: scala, scala.js

I know that for in Scala.js (cannot use `java.text.DecimalFormat`) I can write this:

```
val number = 1.2345
println(f"$x%.2f") // "1.23"
```

However, this doesn't seem to work:

```
val decimalPlaces = 2
println(f"$x%.${decimalPlaces}f")
// [error] Missing conversion operator in '%'; use %% for literal %, %n for newline      f"$x%.${decimalPlaces}f"

// also doesn't work: (f"$x%." + decimalPlaces + "f").toFloat
```

How can I achieve a variable decimal precision?

Comment: Nowhere in your `println` lines you are referring to `number`

Comment: `s"%.${decimalPlaces}f".format(number)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
val number = 1.2345
val decimalPlaces = 2
println(("%." + decimalPlaces + "f").format(number))
```

There is an implicit call to `StringLike` for `format`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the reason it doesn't work is that nowhere in the expression:

```
    s"$number%.$decimalPlacesf" # DOESN'T WORK
```

we are providing the order on how should the variables be resolved.

You need to artificially enforce it. Similarly to @nattyddubbs's answer:

```
val number = 1.2345
val decimalPlaces = 3

val format = s"%.${decimalPlaces}f"
println(format.format(number)) # 1.235
```